# I guess I'm French, tall and strong

Tags: riddle, word

I guess I'm French
tall and strong.
winds come and go,
though they cannot blow me over.
people buy me and sell me
and I am very common
on the street and roads
but they rarely build me without help
my rival is short compared to me
take me apart, and you've got me cornered
I may have a tail, depending on your knowledge

Comment: Note: I'm bad at rhyming, and this is my first post here, so don't mind my bad wording.

Comment: Notre Dame? Eiffel Tower?

Comment: HotAirBalloon ?

Comment: Please don't make guesses in comments. If you have an answer that you think fits the riddle well, write it in a proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> the Eiffel Tower?

I guess I'm French

> The Eiffel Tower is in France, and is generally considered a French icon.

Tall and strong. Winds come and go, though they cannot blow me over.

> The Eiffel Tower is tall and made from latticed wrought iron metal, and while wind can blow through it due to the way the lattice is designed, the tower obviously can't get blown over.

People buy me and sell me and I am very common on the street and roads, but they rarely build me without help.

> The first half of this probably refers to Eiffel Tower souvenirs, miniatures and LEGO sets, which would commonly be sold in stores and tourist traps. The latter is probably speaking of Eiffel Tower LEGO sets and similar DIY build-your-own kits, which are probably difficult to build without some help or an instruction manual.

My rival is short compared to me.

> This refers to the much shorter counterpart of the Eiffel Tower, [the Las Vegas Eiffel Tower in Paris Las Vegas.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Las_Vegas)

Take me apart, and you've got me cornered. I may have a tail, depending on your knowledge.

> Not completely sure what this refers to, but it might be referencing the fact that a broadcasting antenna was added to the tower in 1957, which would give the tower something of a "tail."

Comment: pretty close - the last part didn't really fit in since it was sort of added to the top of the tower, but yeah, nice! +1

Answer (score 0):

Most of the arguments made in @Sciborg's answer can also apply to the

> Statue of Liberty

> It is French made, very strong and tall, it is sold as soveinirs in NY and very tough to build. Also there is a smaller version in Vegas.

For the last clue

> inside of the statue is the winding stair which may be the "tail"? Not sure what Cornered means though

Comment: nope, the stair is inside of the statue, and you're missing a lot of other arguments too.